# How to delete rows where cell contains a specific end letter?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am new to Excel, and am trying to learn some shortcuts. How would I go about creating a formula to delete an entire row if the first cell in that row contains a word that ends with the letter "T"?

Comment: A formula to delete a row?  Are you thinking about a script in VBA?

Comment: I'm not sure, but basically I want it such that "if cell A1's content ends in the letter 't,' then delete the entire row. And continue"

Comment: You will want to create script for that, and as such, would need to start writing a macro.  Do you have any experience with writing script for VBA?  There are many posts out there describing how to conditionally delete rows.  Take a look around, research something up, then come back with a more objective question related to what is going on with your code.

Comment: Filter for `*t` and then delete the resulting rows, no formula or vba needed for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do the automatic operation of finding the content which ends with letter "t" you might need to write a vba code, however with the help of excel formula it can aid you to atleast see which rows to delete, below is sample.

[image]

=IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="t","Delete","Do not Delete")

Hope this helps!!

Regards, Hafeez

Answer (score 0):

I agree with above comment. Formulas are easier than VBA if you can avoid it. Once you create that column you can sort it so all deletes will be grouped together and then delete all of those rows in one shot.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).